# Set datetimepicker format depending on the chosen value in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, datepicker, haml

I would like the datetimepicker to show only days if the user chose "Days" in dropdown and show months if the user chose "Months".

The code is inside haml file:

```
= select_tag 'date_format', options_for_select(["Days", "Months"]), onchange: "myFunction()"

= text_field_tag :from, class: 'datepick'

 :javascript
  function myFunction() {
      var value = document.getElementById("date_format").value;
      if (value == "Days") {
        $(".datepick").datepicker("destroy");
        $(".datepick").datetimepicker({
          format: 'd.m.Y'
        });
      } else if (value == "Months") {
        $(".datepick").datetimepicker("destroy");
        $(".datepick").datepicker({
          format: "mm/yyyy"
        });
      }
  }
```

Right now it doesn't work well. Please help me to find out where I made a mistake. How to overwrite (".datepick")?

Comment: add class datepick to your select_tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only option I've found is to create another text_field_tag and hide/show it:

```
= text_field_tag :from, class: 'datepick'
= text_field_tag :from, class: 'datetimepick'

:javascript
  function myFunction() {
      var value = document.getElementById("date_format").value;
      if (value == "Days") {
        $(".datepick").hide();
        $(".datetimepick").show();
        $(".datetimepick").datetimepicker({
          format: 'd/m/Y'
        });
      } else if (value == "Months") {
        $(".datetimepick").hide();
        $(".datepick").show();
        $(".datepick").datepicker({
          format: "mm/yyyy"
        });
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with the 'dateFormat' and 'formatDate' option instead of 'format'

Comment: You didn't understand a problem. In case of chosen "months" I get a calendar with only months - this works good. But in case of chosen "days" I get 2 calendars - one with only months, another one with days.